# recyclerview list is not displaying in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below code value am adding values to account_name the after that using that adapter doing the set adapter.response is coming the server but values are not adding to the list and list is also displaying.

For displaying used the recyclerview to display the values .

can any one help me where did the mistake

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.genworks.oppm.Adapter.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:32)
        at com.genworks.oppm.Adapter.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:19)
```

updated code:

**Activity.java:**

```
for(SyncBlocks syncBlocks1:syncBlocks){

                        String label=syncBlocks1.getLabel();

                        ArrayList<SynFields> synFields=syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        ArrayList<SynFields> jsonArray=syncBlocks1.getFields();

                        for(SynFields synFields1:synFields){

                            String name=synFields1.getName();

                            Object values = synFields1.getValue().toString();

                            try {

                                if (values instanceof JSONObject) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new
                                            JSONObject(String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue()));
                                    String value=jsonObject1.getString("value");
                                }else if (values instanceof String) {
                                    //here, you get string

                                     String value =  synFields1.getValue().toString();
                                    //account_name.addAll(value);
                                    String value_names= String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue());
                                   // Log.e("account_name", String.valueOf(account_name.add(value)));
                                    account_name.add(value_names);

                                    //account_name.add(value);

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),account_name);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                    }
```

**MyAdapter.java:**

```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mSynFields=new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> synFieldsArrayList) {
        mContext=context;
        mSynFields=synFieldsArrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

       holder.name.setText(mSynFields.get(position));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mSynFields.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView country, name, city;
        ImageView iv;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subHeaderText);
            city = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subHeadingText);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You first store your data information by looping in the list variable and outside of the loop first make sure your recyclerview is cast, then configure the layoutmanager and finally recyclerview the adapter.

Comment: @JavadShakouri where i did the mistake

Comment: You called LayoutManager after you called the adapter
You first need to set LayoutManager, then apply the adapter and set the code and remove it from the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you invoke `inflate` method from a `null` reference(`inflater`).

You have to initialize your `inflater` like below.

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()); // add this line.

        //or you can do like below
        // View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, parent, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }
```

Comment: holder.name.setText(mSynFields.get(position)); how to set the getvalue()

Comment: what is the problem with this `holder.name.setText(mSynFields.get(position));`. this should works.

Comment: list is not displaying only one value is displaying

Comment: then, the problem in your activity where you parse your data using for loop.

Comment: for(SynFields synFields1:synFields) {

                                    String name = synFields1.getName();

                                    if(name.equals("industry")){

                                        String ownership_type=synFields1.getLabel();
                                        ownership_types.add(ownership_type);
                                    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207093/discussion-between-jyothi-dadi-and-jakir-hossain).

Answer (score 0):

Place the below lines outside the `for` loop with the entire list as the parameter for the adapter that has been built inside the loop:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),account_name));
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

In addition to the above, you are passing `account_name` which is of type `ArrayList<String>` whereas in your adapter, your constructor is expecting `synFieldsArrayList` which is of type `ArrayList<SynFields>`. Both need to be of the same type. Either change your adapter, or your activity to make sure both are of same type.
In your `MyViewHolder` constructor, add:

```
Context context = parent.getContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, parent, false);
```

Comment: Which is? Post some description

Comment: see my updated code in that account_name is showing error

Comment: By the way, you have 3 closing parenthesis here: `new MyAdapter(getContext(),account_name.add(value)));`. There should be only 2. And what is the `error` that is being shown? And in which function of the activity are you triggering this code in?

Comment: account_name declared as a arraylist

Comment: See updated answer. You have a difference between the type of list you are sending, and accepting in the adapter.

Comment: yes your correct .But it is not accepting to changing both the types to arrayList<SyncFields> contains a string and object with same key name value

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you mean, could you explain again please.

Comment: Ah. It's an `inflater` exception. Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
ArrayList<SynFields> account_name=new ArrayList();

String label=syncBlocks1.getLabel();

ArrayList<SynFields> synFields=syncBlocks1.getFields();

ArrayList<SynFields> jsonArray=syncBlocks1.getFields();

for(SynFields synFields1:synFields){

String name=synFields1.getName();

   Object values = synFields1.getValue();

      try {

          if (values instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new 
                 JSONObject(String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue()));
          }else if (values instanceof String) {
            //here, you get string
            String value = String.valueOf(synFields1.getValue());
            account_name.add(value);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),account_name);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));    
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),account_name); account_name is showing error

Comment: See my adapter and activity

Comment: you can change type generic account_name ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<SynFields> and add item to list and set account_name new list to adapter

Comment: value is showing an error please check my updated code

Comment: What is JSONObject used for?

Comment: {
                                "name": "parent_id",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "2x37",
                                    "label": "Davis Jennifer"
                                },
                                "label": "Related to",
                                "uitype": "66"
                            },

Comment: {
                                "name": "eventstatus",
                                "value": "Planned",
                                "label": "Status",
                                "uitype": "15"
                            },

Comment: sometime value is string and object